# How to exceed the limitation of FeatureLayer?

Tags: arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I using ArcMap published a Feature Service with about 5000 polygons, and on the ArcGIS Server, I am pretty ensure that "Maximum Number of Records returned by Server" is set to 10000. however, when this FeatureLayer is displayed in a SceneView,(yes, we need SceneView for 3d) I found that some polygons are not displayed in Chrome browser(latest, verion 70) !
I searched on the net, and it seems that ArcGIS js 4.9 can only display 2000-3000 features. Could you please how to exceed this limitation, whether it have some graphic card settings I can adjust to try ? Thanks!

Comment: I never heard of or encounter this limitation before. Can you post the page where you found that information? Go to your MapService REST endpoint and do a query on your layer with the following definition expression (where) `OBJECTID < 5000`. If the request returns 4999 features, you will be assured that there is no such limitation.

Comment: that limit is doc in: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html section: "Known limitations", and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268255/avoiding-feature-limit-exceeded-on-layer-in-arcgis-javascript-api  futhurmore, I really found polygons missing on a FeatureLayer with 5000 polygons in SceneView. 5000 is not very big, we need to display at most 20000 polygons in SceneView....

Comment: Ok, do you know if this a per layer limitation or per MapScene? If it's per layer, you could split your layer into multiple layers using definition expressions such `OBJECTID < 2000`, and `OBJECTID >= 2000 AND OBJECTID < 4000` and so on.

Comment: I think that limitation is per SceneView, (the "Known limitation" is doc in the SceneView, not FeatureLayer, as the URL I posted previous)
and thanks for your suggestion, however, 
splitting the layer into sub-layers, would cause other functionalities complex, e.g: searching features in 
these sub-layers. and it's not easy to split a layer by certain criteria, consider at most we have 20000 polygons ...

Comment: what about loading and unloading features on map extent move? you can query the feature using the map extent as the bounding box...

Comment: thanks, I will try it tomorrow. another is, I hope that limitation can be adjusted by changing browser/graphics card settings, consider the nowadays graphics card, that can display millions triangles a second, why 5000 polygons is a limit?

Comment: Probably because WebGL is not available for SceneView right now (as mentionned in the answer of the second link you provided). Without WebGL, the graphic card wont be of any use I think.

Comment: @chenzero version 4.10 of the JS API was just released yesterday. From the patch notes it looks like they have have removed this limitation: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/release-notes/index.html#large-line-and-polygon-datasets-in-a-webscene

Comment: @BigGerman thanks! At last, I found the REALreason of missing polygons, the height of our polygon data is wrong. I am sorry to make this in the wrong way before.  and wrote a html to demo SceneView with lots of polygons. https://codepen.io/stzdzyhs/pen/qLPrvZ      please save any unsave files before opening that URL :)  Thanks for you all !

Comment: Your demo runs very smoothly on my computer using FireFox 64.0 (64bit)